# Ubuntu will not allow me to add a repository, why can't it access PPA?

Tags: networking, java, ppa, repository

When I type in this command:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
```

The system echos something along the lines of "Can't access lanchpad.net PPA, please check your internet connection"

My Internet connection is working fine, and just to see if it would help I reset my modem and router. Still, no luck.

I have also tried to add this PPA via Ubuntu Software Center but that has not changed anything.

How do I get past this error? At this point I'm considering totally re-installing Ubuntu 13.04

Comment: Are you behind a proxy? Do you get errors when you do `sudo apt-get update`?

Comment: Try add this `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8`. It works for me.

Comment: If you are behind a proxy, try using `sudo -E add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java` to get the environment settings.

Answer (score 1):

try adding the source manually into /etc/apt/sources.list  or do it through the software manager add sources.  the option explained https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/java in technical details about this ppa

Answer (score 1):

If you are behind a proxy set the https_proxy environmental variable to your custom setting, for example:

```
export https_proxy=http://myproxy.domain.net:8080/
```

Then run sudo add-apt-repository with the -E flag to pass the environmental variables:

```
sudo -E add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
```

For some reason add-apt-repository doesn't use the proxy settings for apt.